# reverse every alternate k nodes

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault

I m new ds. I was trying this question-Given a linked list, write a function to reverse every alternate k nodes (where k is an input to the function) in an efficient way. Give the complexity of your algorithm. My code is giving me segmentation fault. Help!

‎

```
struct node* func(struct node* head, int k)
{
    struct node* run, *list1;
    run =head->next;
    list1=head;

    int count =0;

    struct node *list2=NULL;

while(list1!=NULL && count++<k)
{
    list1->next=list2;
    list2=list1;
    list1=run;
    run=list1->next;
}

head=list2;

while(list2->next!=NULL && list2!=NULL)
    list2=list2->next;

list2->next=list1;

while(list1!=NULL && count++<k-1)
    list1=list1->next;

if(list1!=NULL)
    list1->next=func( head, k);
    return head;
}
```

Comment: have you checked the core dump to pin point the location of memory fault?

Comment: One thing that greatly facilitates debugging is using meaningful variable names. The names `func`, `list1`, and `list2` are not very descriptive of what these variables are used for.

Comment: What to do if the number of list nodes is not a multiple of k?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node* func_aux(struct node* head, struct node* rev, int k){
    struct node* next;
    if(k == 0 || head == NULL)
        return rev;
    next = head->next;
    head->next = rev;
    return func_aux(next, head, --k);
}

struct node* func(struct node* head, int k){
    struct node* kth_node;
    int i=0;
    for(kth_node=head;kth_node;kth_node=kth_node->next,++i){
        if(k==i)break;
    }
    return func_aux(head, kth_node, k);
}
```